# Как загрузить картинку с ip камеры через Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, onvif

Когда я отправляю http запрос Ip камере (Onvif протокол)

```html
    "<GetSnapshotUri xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl\">" +
          "<ProfileToken>PROFILE_000</ProfileToken></GetSnapshotUri>";
```

Я получаю ответ содержащий url картинки:

```html
....
 <s:Body><trt:GetSnapshotUriResponse><trt:MediaUri> 
 <tt:Uri>http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi</tt:Uri> 
 <tt:InvalidAfterConnect>false</tt:InvalidAfterConnect> 
 <tt:InvalidAfterReboot>false</tt:InvalidAfterReboot><tt:Timeout>PT5S</tt:Timeout></trt:MediaUri> 
 </trt:GetSnapshotUriResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Я пробовал использовать [image_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader) плагин - не работает.
  Я могу открыть эту ссылку в браузере (Chrome), правда меньшего разрешения, но немого отобразить картинку через Widget Image.network('http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi')

Я получаю ошибку

```html
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 401, http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
#2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Я нашел ответ для Java

```html
URL url = new URL("http://webacm-ip-adr:8084/snapshot.cgi");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
String jpg = "sample.jpg";
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(jpg);
IOUtils.copy(input, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен [MJPEG reader (для .cgi формата)](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mjpeg), думаю этот плагин вам подойдет. Ещё есть [такой плагин](https://pub.dev/packages/mjpeg), но он дергает нативную часть и для него необходимо писать виджет отображения.